# 50-Percent Rule

Tags: c, malloc, free

I am writing a program that tests dynamic memory allocation to see how well the 50-percent rule holds.

The program has 10,000 pointers to dynamically allocated blocks of memory. It also has an array to store the size of each block. It should:

1. Use `malloc()` to dynamically allocated a block of memory for every element of `ptrList`. These blocks should have sizes that are selected randomly in the range of 1 to 10,000 bytes and the block size should be stored in the `sizeList` array.
2. After initial block allocation, the program should repeatedly free blocks and allocate new ones. This should loop for 100,000 iterations. On each iteration, an index in `ptrList` is chosen at random, the block is freed, and then replaced with a new dynamically allocated block with random size.
3. After every 100 iterations, it should print out a line that shows the iteration count, the approximate heap size (determined by the difference between the highest and lowest memory addresses contained in any of the blocks), and the total size of all blocks pointed to by `ptrList`.

I have my program coded like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>   /* for pthreads */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* for exit */

/** Number of memory blocks to allocate/deallocate. */
#define BLOCK_COUNT 10000

/** Number of free/malloc operations to perform */
#define TEST_LENGTH 100000

/** Maximum size of an allocated block. */
#define SIZE_LIMIT 10000

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  // Array of pointers to all blocks that have been allocated.
  char *ptrList[ BLOCK_COUNT ];

  // Array of sizes for each block, so we can know how much memory we're using.
  int sizeList[ BLOCK_COUNT ];

  // Insert your code here
  for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {

      int minimum = 0;
      int maximum = 0;
      int total = 0, remainder = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < BLOCK_COUNT; i++) {
          int size = (rand() % SIZE_LIMIT) + 1;
          ptrList[i] = malloc (size);
          sizeList[i] = size;
          total += size;
          int heapsize = (int)ptrList[i];

          if (i == 0) {
              maximum = heapsize;
              minimum = heapsize;
          }
          else {
              if (heapsize > maximum) {
                  maximum = heapsize;
              }
              if (heapsize < minimum) {
                  minimum = heapsize;
              }
          }
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < TEST_LENGTH; i++) {
          int index = rand() % BLOCK_COUNT;
          int size = (rand() % SIZE_LIMIT) + 1;
          free(ptrList[index]);
          total -= sizeList[index];
          ptrList[index] = malloc (size);
          sizeList[index] = size;
          total += sizeList[index];
          int heapsize = (int)ptrList[index];

          if (heapsize > maximum) {
              maximum = heapsize;
          }
          if (heapsize < minimum) {
              minimum = heapsize;
          }
      }

      if (j > 0) {
          remainder = j % 100;
      }

      if (remainder == 0 ) {
          //printf("%d", example);
          printf("%d %d %d\n", j, maximum - minimum, total);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < BLOCK_COUNT; i++) {
          free(ptrList[i]);
      }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Am I approaching the allocation/deallocation of memory the right way? My program compiles and runs (without output) before I implemented the `for` loop with `int j`. It hangs after I implemented it, so perhaps someone can help me pin the problem there as well.

**Edit:** The 50-percent rule is the total size of all blocks divided by the approximation of the heap size will generally be around 50 percent.

Comment: "It hangs after I implemented it" - that is generally considered a problem...

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes, I'm not quite sure what is causing it. Commenting out `for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)` allows the program to run to completion. As soon as I comment that line back in, the program hangs. I have tried adding a `for` loop to free memory at the end of each iteration as well.

Comment: Just as an FYI, random allocations and frees have historically been a *very bad model* for program memory usage.  There are not many solid conclusions you can draw from such an experiment.  You may get more interesting data by substituting your allocator into a couple big processes -- like a web browser (which runs continuously) or a compiler (which ends after processing a file).

Comment: Does it hang, or is it taking a long time?  You should have it print progress messages.  You should check the result of malloc for null.

Comment: I'm also curious as to what you mean by the "50 percent rule".  If you mean that 50 percent of heap memory would be occupied when nominally full, that would be evidence of a fairly poor heap manager.

Comment: This question is begging for a -1 with no reference to what the "50 percent rule" means...

Comment: Sorry all, I realized that the program did not like how I was handling the modulus. I fixed it and it now prints output. I have also edited my original post to include the 50-percent rule. The results seem correct except for the approximation of heap size. I realized that I was returning the difference between the highest and lowest byte size. How may I find the highest and lowest memory addresses contained in a block?

Comment: Technically, in most modern operating systems using a platform where the memory management is handled by the kernel, the size of the heap is not necessarily finite (by installed memory size) since it can page memory to the hard drive. If you want a truely finite memory allocation library, see the DOOM source code for their zone allocation. I have used it to learn how to implement my own heaps and memory management that reside on top of the OS within the process using it. Of course, you will need to initialize it with memory allocated by the kernel.

Comment: `maximum` and `minimum` should have type `uintptr_t`, and you should simply cast the address of the allocated block's first and last byte to `uintptr_t` to compare.

Comment: @WilliamtheCoderer: The size of the heap in C is always finite because `sizeof(void *)` and `CHAR_BIT` are constants, and the size of the heap is bounded by `1<<(sizeof(void *) * CHAR_BIT)`.

Comment: When programming in Win32, the standard C library just calls GlobalAlloc() under the covers.

Comment: There's still a limited amount of address space.

Comment: @R.. Hmm, I am a bit confused on how to calculate the fraction of the heap size that's being used by the blocks currently allocated. What I attempted to do was take the sum of `maximum heap size - minimum heap size` and divide this by `total`. The difference between my maximum heap size and my minimum heap size is currently in the `52,000,000` range, while the sample output for numbers I should be receiving are in the `98,000,000` range. Can you think of a reason for this discrepancy? Maybe an error in my logic somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides cruft (egregiously unnecessary code) you've got some problems with variables and loops:  Your `for (int i = 0; i < TEST_LENGTH; i++)...` loop, which implements step 2 of the spec, is the loop within which, every 100 steps, you should print current stats.  Having an outer `for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)` loop and testing `j%100` remainders is nonsense.

For debugging a problem like that, knock two or three zeroes off each of the big numbers BLOCK_COUNT, TEST_LENGTH, SIZE_LIMIT, change the `j` loop limit to 10, and add a `printf("j=..." ...)` after `for (int j ...) {` so you can tell what's happening.  With such changes, you will see:

```
  j=0 0 0
  0 556736 507760
  j=1 0 0
  j=2 0 0
  j=3 0 0
  ...
```

and then can conclude that your program seemed to hang because it was slowly counting j up to 100 to get to `j%100 == 0`.

Now I'll mention two minor cruft items to remove, and after that will mention a major problem with your program.

Instead of

```
  int minimum = 0;
  int maximum = 0;
  ...
     if (i == 0) {
        maximum = heapsize;
        minimum = heapsize;
     }
     else {
       if (heapsize > maximum) {
          maximum = heapsize;
     }
     if (heapsize < minimum) {
          minimum = heapsize;
     }
```

write

```
  int minimum = MAX_INT;
  int maximum = 0;
  ...
     if (heapsize > maximum)
        maximum = heapsize;
     if (heapsize < minimum)
        minimum = heapsize;
```

(or possibly a variant of MAX_INT) and (if you needed `j` and/or `remainder`, which you don't) instead of

```
  if (j > 0) {
      remainder = j % 100;
  }

  if (remainder == 0 ) {
     ...
```

you would write

```
  if (j>0 && j%100 == 0 ) {
     ...
```

A major problem with your program:  When you say `free(ptrList[index]);` in part 2, you might be freeing the item that accounted for the current minimum or maximum memory addresses.  One way to solve this problem is maintain priority queues with min/max values and fifo discipline too; what you will find simpler, I think, is to not track min/max while allocating, but instead just have a loop to find min/max right before each printout.

A minor problem with your program:  The maximum address used is not `ptrList[index]` for some index, but `ptrList[index]+sizeList[index]`.

Comment: Thanks, I initially had `if (j == 0 || j%100 == 0)`, but the program did not like this. I will try to go through my code and remove as much cruft as I can, but right now I am stuck on the minimum problem. SIZE_LIMIT is limited to 10000, and heap sizes must be much larger than that for the `max - min` to be in the `98,000,000` range. Running my program several times, the maximum heap size changes as it should, but the minimum heap size remains the same and I can't seem to pinpoint where the error lies in my logic.

Comment: You may have written that comment while I was editing 2nd to last paragraph, re min/max problems.  Re "SIZE_LIMIT is limited to..." just change the constants to whatever's easy to work with while debugging, eg only do 3 or 4 passes with half a dozen multimegabyte blocks, so you can print all the sizes and check manually; when it all works, correct the constants to required values.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed finding `min` and `max` until just before the print. I'm still having issues with `minimum` remaining the same. Perhaps I am calculating the minimum the wrong way? Is the fractional heap size (max - min) / total? Maximum values seem to be okay, but I can't get the other values in check.

Comment: If memory is allocated out of a set of contiguous pages of real memory on a single-user system, I'd expect the fraction to be total/(max-min).  But when it's allocated out of virtual memory pages that can be anywhere, on a multiuser system among other processes also allocating memory, that need not be the case.  Are you writing code for an OS course and want to study allocation details?  Or is it for a C course?